# Remove upload file from input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

HTML code:

```
<img src="../img/attach.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer">
    <input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" style="display:none">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#file1").change(function(){
        var arr = $('#file1')[0];
        var fileName = $('#file1')[0].files[0].name;
        var fileName2 = $('#file1')[0].files[0].size;
        fileName2 /= 100000;
        var size = fileName2.toFixed(2);
        if(fileName){
            $(".attach").html("1. <span class='fileName'>"+ fileName + "</span> " +size+ "Mb Loaded <img src='../img/bin.png'>").css("display","block");
            $(".attach img").on("click", function() {
                delete arr.files[0];
                console.log(arr.files[0]);
            });
        }
    });
```

I need to remove upload file after clicked on img... Can I do it use jQuery or I need some library such a Basic plus UI. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$('#file1').val("")`

Comment: Thank, it works.. but is it correct way to remove files from file input??

Answer (score 7):

You can use `$('#file1').val('');`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#upfile1').on('click',function(){
    $('#file1').remove();
});
```